# How to spawn a node on a scheduled timer loop in a override touch began method

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, 2d-games

So I am creating a shooting game for iOS and I am having trouble looping a bullet spawn method that is activated by touching and moving a joystick. I've tried what seems like everything but with coding there is always a right way.

Here is my bullet defined:

```
 func spawnBullet1(){
    self.addChild(bullet1)
    bullet1.position = CGPoint (x: gun1.position.x , y:  
    gun1.position.y) // Bullet spawn @ anchor point
    bullet1.xScale = 0.5
    bullet1.yScale = 0.5
    //physics, not important right now 
    bullet1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet1.size)
    bullet1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet1
    bullet1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy1
    bullet1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    let wait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5) //bullet spawn wait
    let block:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock(spawnBullet1) //re-spawn bullet
    let seq3:SKAction = SKAction.sequence( [ wait, block ]) //sequence
    self.runAction(seq3) //execution   
}
```

My joystick in my touches begins here:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent   
 event:UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(joystick.frame, location)) {
            stickActive = true

        }else{
            stickActive = false
        }

        if stickActive == true {
            spawnBullet1()
        }
```

Obviously I left out some details about the joystick because that's not the part I'm having trouble with. The problem I am having is that my first bullet launches just as planned and works great, however, when the second bullet is spawned the app crashes, saying that it cannot add `SKnode` when node already has a parent or something like that, basically its saying that I am duplicating the bullet the wrong way and I can't figure out what the right way is.

Comment: can you help me here? lol @Mate Hegedus